# Are all single-celled organisms Bacteria?

Tags: immunology, bacteriology

I read that "Bacteria are one-celled organisms that can multiply by division", are all one-celled organisms bacteria or are there any more narrow definitions?

Comment: You mean more narrow definition for bacteria?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, many [unicellular organisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicellular_organism) are not bacteria. Examples include (but certainly not limited to); some fungi, [chlorella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorella) algae, and [archaea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea).

Bacteria are one of three domains in the classification of life. You can find more about the bacteria domain at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteria#Classification_and_identification) page (It's a long and complex history which is hard to summarise here) and about [the domains here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-domain_system). This last defines bacteria loosely consisting of "**prokaryotic cells possessing primarily diacyl glycerol (DAG) diester lipids in their membranes and bacterial rRNA, no nuclear membrane, traditionally classified as bacteria.**"

The composition of lipids in their membrane (DAG-esters) differentiates them from another major class of prokaryotes — Archaea, which have isoprenoid lipids in their membranes.

*Initially Archaea was called Archaebacteria. Because of significant differences, including the membrane composition, they are now grouped into a different kingdom.*

Answer (score 7):

No, as @rg255 already mentioned, bacteria are one of the main kingdoms of life:

[image: Phylogenetic tree showing the three main domains of life (Bacteria, Archaea and Eukaryotes)]

The [Bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteria) and [Archaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaea) are all unicellular organisms (though there are strange Archea like the [Pyrodictium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrodictium) genus that are borderline multicellular). The Eukaryota include all plants, fungi and animals but there are also unicellular Eukaryotes. For example, [Paremecium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramecium) is a unicellular animal, brewer's yeast ([*S. cerevisiae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae)) is a unicellular fungus and [Chlorella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorella) is a unicellular plant.

In other words, all bacteria are unicellular but not all unicellular organisms are bacteria.